# Server Program won't read from Stream

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am currently trying to write a TCP client/server application. I feel I've done a poor job since I am fairly new to this in terms of C# (coming from Java).

My client have this code:

```
    public static void SendPlejeFamilieObjekt(PlejeFamilie pfamilie)
    {
        try
        {
            InitConnection();
            if (_isConnected)
            {
                _sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE");

                if (_sReader.ReadLine().Equals("AUTH_GIVEN"))
                {
                    #region Send Plejefamilie Objekt
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.CPRKvinde);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.CPRMand);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.NavnKvinde);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.NavnMand);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Addresse);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.MobilKvinde);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.MobilMand);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.HjemmeTelefon);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.StillingKvinde);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.StillingMand);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailKvinde);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailMand);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailFaelles);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.GodkendtDato.ToShortDateString());
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.PlejeForaeldreUdd);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.AntalKurserIAar);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.AntalBoernGodkendt);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Vilkaar);
                    _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Status);
                    #endregion Send Plejefamilie Objekt
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            EndConnection();
        }
    }
```

And it works all the way down to sending "SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE". I've checked this by printing to console.

Now in my server code it looks like this:

```
    private static void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
        Console.WriteLine("Handling client: {0}", client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        Console.WriteLine("Streams Acquired");
        bool bClientConnected = client.Connected;
        Console.WriteLine("bClientConnected {0}", bClientConnected.ToString());
        String sData = sReader.ReadLine();
        List<String> list;
        List<Note> nList;
        List<Note> nList2;
        while (bClientConnected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sData);
            switch (sData)
            {
                #region Modtag Plejefamilie
                case "SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE":
                    Console.WriteLine("Receiving PlejeFamilie");
                    sWriter.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                    sWriter.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                    list = new List<String>();
                    while (!(sData = sReader.ReadLine()).Equals("END"))
                    {
                        list.Add(sData);
                    }
                    ServerPlejeFamilie spf = new ServerPlejeFamilie();
                    spf.Info = list;
                    pfStack.Push(spf);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", spf.Info[0]);
                    break;
```

The program stops running after this line of code: `Console.WriteLine("bClientConnected {0}", bClientConnected.ToString());`

I cannot figure out why.
Below is all the code for both classes just in case you need it:

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Smart_Journal.Familie;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Smart_Journal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DBM is our Database Manager. This will handle sending and receiving of data from the server.
    /// You should NOT call these functions directly. Instead, call the functions in the Utility class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class DBM
    {
        private static TcpClient _client;
        private static StreamReader _sReader;
        private static StreamWriter _sWriter;
        private static bool _isConnected;
        private static int portNum = 8888;
        private static String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

        private static void InitConnection()
        {
            _client = new TcpClient();
            _client.Connect(ipAddress, portNum);

            _sReader = new StreamReader(_client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            _sWriter = new StreamWriter(_client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            _isConnected = true;
        }

        private static void EndConnection()
        {
            _sWriter.WriteLine("END");

            _sReader.Close();
            _sWriter.Close();
            _client.Close();
            _isConnected = false;
        }

        public static void SendPlejeFamilieObjekt(PlejeFamilie pfamilie)
        {
            try
            {
                InitConnection();
                if (_isConnected)
                {
                    _sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE");

                    if (_sReader.ReadLine().Equals("AUTH_GIVEN"))
                    {
                        #region Send Plejefamilie Objekt
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.CPRKvinde);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.CPRMand);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.NavnKvinde);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.NavnMand);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Addresse);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.MobilKvinde);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.MobilMand);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.HjemmeTelefon);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.StillingKvinde);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.StillingMand);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailKvinde);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailMand);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.EmailFaelles);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.GodkendtDato.ToShortDateString());
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.PlejeForaeldreUdd);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.AntalKurserIAar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.AntalBoernGodkendt);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Vilkaar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pfamilie.Status);
                        #endregion Send Plejefamilie Objekt
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                EndConnection();
            }
        }

        public static void SendPlejeBarnObjekt(PlejeBarn pbarn)
        {
            try
            {
                InitConnection();
                if (_isConnected)
                {
                    _sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_PLEJEBARN");

                    if (_sReader.ReadLine().Equals("AUTH_GIVEN"))
                    {
                        #region Send Plejebarn Objekt
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.CPR);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Navn);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.FolkeregisterAdresse);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Email);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Telefon);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Sagsbehandler);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Konsulent);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.Aflastning);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.NuvaerendeForanstaltning);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.AnbringelsesDato.ToShortDateString());
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(pbarn.UdskrivningsDato.ToShortDateString());
                        _sWriter.WriteLine("PLEJEBARN_B");

                        foreach (Note n in pbarn.Bemaerkninger)
                        {
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Dato.ToShortDateString());
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Navn);
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Tekst);
                        }
                        _sWriter.WriteLine("END_PLEJEBARN_B");
                        _sWriter.WriteLine("PLEJEBARN_TF");

                        foreach (Note n in pbarn.TideligereForanstaltninger)
                        {
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Dato);
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Navn);
                            _sWriter.WriteLine(n.Tekst);
                        }
                        _sWriter.WriteLine("END_PLEJEBARN_TF");
                        #endregion Send Plejebarn Objekt
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                EndConnection();
            }
        }

        public static void SendBiologiskFamilieObjekt(BiologiskFamilie bfamilie)
        {
            try
            {
                InitConnection();
                if (_isConnected)
                {
                    _sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_BIOLOGISKFAMILIE");

                    if (_sReader.ReadLine().Equals("AUTH_GIVEN"))
                    {
                        #region Send Biologiskfamilie Objekt
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.CPRMor);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.CPRFar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.NavnMor);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.NavnFar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.Addresse);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.MobilMor);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.MobilFar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.HjemmeTelefon);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.EmailMor);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.EmailFar);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.EmailFaelles);
                        _sWriter.WriteLine(bfamilie.ForaeldreMyndighed);
                        #endregion Send Biologiskfamilie Objekt
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                EndConnection();
            }
        }

        public static PlejeFamilie HentPlejeFamilieObjekt(String s)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static PlejeBarn HentPlejeBarnObjekt(String s)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static BiologiskFamilie HentBiologiskFamilie(String s)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Smart_Journal_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpListener _server;
        private static bool _isRunning;
        private static int port;
        private static Stack<ServerPlejeFamilie> pfStack = new Stack<ServerPlejeFamilie>();
        private static Stack<ServerPlejeBarn> pbStack = new Stack<ServerPlejeBarn>();
        private static Stack<ServerBiologiskFamilie> bfStack = new Stack<ServerBiologiskFamilie>();
        private static Stack<Request> rStack = new Stack<Request>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            args = new string[1];
            args[0] = "8888";
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                port = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Booting up Server with port number {0}...", port);
            _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address Assigned: {0}", IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)_server.LocalEndpoint).Address.ToString()));
            _server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server Successfully Started");

            _isRunning = true;

            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SendToDataBase));
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RetrieveFromDataBase));
            t.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to write data to the Database");
            t1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Ready to read data from the Database");
            LoopClients();
        }

        private static void SendToDataBase(object obj)
        {
            while (_isRunning)
            {
                if (pfStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    ServerPlejeFamilie pfobj = pfStack.Pop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Popping PlejeFamilieObject: {0}", pfobj.Info[0] + "," + pfobj.Info[1]);
                }

                if (pbStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    ServerPlejeBarn pbobj = pbStack.Pop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Popping PlejeBarnObject: {0}", pbobj.Info[0]);
                }

                if (bfStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    ServerBiologiskFamilie bfobj = bfStack.Pop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Popping BiologiskFamilieObject: {0}", bfobj.Info[0] + "," + bfobj.Info[1]);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void RetrieveFromDataBase(object obj)
        {
            while (_isRunning)
            {

            }
        }

        private static void LoopClients()
        {
            while (_isRunning)
            {
                //wait for client connection
                TcpClient newClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient();

                Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
                t.Start(newClient);
            }
        }

        private static void HandleClient(object obj)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
            Console.WriteLine("Handling client: {0}", client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            Console.WriteLine("Streams Acquired");
            bool bClientConnected = client.Connected;
            Console.WriteLine("bClientConnected {0}", bClientConnected.ToString());
            String sData = sReader.ReadLine();
            List<String> list;
            List<Note> nList;
            List<Note> nList2;
            while (bClientConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sData);
                switch (sData)
                {
                    #region Modtag Plejefamilie
                    case "SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE":
                        Console.WriteLine("Receiving PlejeFamilie");
                        sWriter.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                        sWriter.Flush();
                        Console.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                        list = new List<String>();
                        while (!(sData = sReader.ReadLine()).Equals("END"))
                        {
                            list.Add(sData);
                        }
                        ServerPlejeFamilie spf = new ServerPlejeFamilie();
                        spf.Info = list;
                        pfStack.Push(spf);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", spf.Info[0]);
                        break;
                    #endregion Modtag Plejefamilie
                    #region Modtag Plejebarn
                    case "SEND_PLEJEBARN":
                        sWriter.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                        sWriter.Flush();
                        list = new List<String>();
                        nList = new List<Note>();
                        nList2 = new List<Note>();
                        while (!(sData = sReader.ReadLine()).Equals("END"))
                        {
                            if (sData.Equals("PLEJEBARN_B"))
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    Note n = new Note();
                                    n.Dato = Convert.ToDateTime(sReader.ReadLine());
                                    n.Navn = sReader.ReadLine();
                                    n.Tekst = sReader.ReadLine();
                                    nList.Add(n);

                                    sData = sReader.ReadLine();
                                } while (!sData.Equals("END_PLEJEBARN_B"));
                            }
                            else if (sData.Equals("PLEJEBARN_TF"))
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    Note n = new Note();
                                    n.Dato = Convert.ToDateTime(sReader.ReadLine());
                                    n.Navn = sReader.ReadLine();
                                    n.Tekst = sReader.ReadLine();
                                    nList2.Add(n);
                                    sData = sReader.ReadLine();
                                } while (!sData.Equals("END_PLEJEBARN_TF"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                list.Add(sData);
                            }
                        }
                        ServerPlejeBarn spb = new ServerPlejeBarn();
                        spb.Info = list;
                        spb.Bemaerkninger = nList;
                        spb.TideligereForanstaltninger = nList2;
                        pbStack.Push(spb);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", spb.Info[0]);
                        break;
                    #endregion Modtag Plejebarn
                    #region Modtag Biologisk Familie
                    case "SEND_BIOLOGISKFAMILIE":
                        sWriter.WriteLine("AUTH_GIVEN");
                        sWriter.Flush();
                        list = new List<String>();
                        while (!(sData = sReader.ReadLine()).Equals("END"))
                        {
                            list.Add(sData);
                        }
                        ServerBiologiskFamilie sbf = new ServerBiologiskFamilie();
                        sbf.Info = list;
                        bfStack.Push(sbf);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", sbf.Info[0]);
                        break;
                    #endregion Modtag Biologisk Familie
                    default:
                        sWriter.WriteLine("NO_AUTH");
                        break;
                }
            }
            sWriter.Close();
            sReader.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? No one at all? That's a first xD

Comment: Why are you not using WCF services (or another webservice technology)?

Comment: I've not been taught thoroughly in those so I went with a more traditional TCP/IP approach. It's for an exam assignment and a real company who will need to use this at some point.

Comment: Well WCF Services would make things so much easier, maybe you should take a look at this technology first, before you decide that you have to code it using the low-level TCP/IP. Some information / tutorial on this technology: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: Even with a Java background, surely this doesn't look correct: `while (bClientConnected)` - `bClientConnected` is a local variable which has been assigned above that place and is never again assigned to after that `while` loop starts. Not the cause of the problem, but a bug nevertheless.

Comment: I find doing it in Java a lot easier @Damien_The_Unbeliever . Especially multithreading.

Comment: Are you missing some _sWriter.Flush() calls in your client? I suspect your client isn't actually sending anything.

Comment: Yes, after this line `_sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE");` I guess. If you add that, It will work. Read/Write operations are blocking, so here both are waiting for the other one to send something.

Comment: @neilh I did what you said and it worked. I sent the object to the server but now the sever hangs after receiving the last line of information. If I try to close the reader/writer/client on the server it says the object doesn't exist any more. If I don't close them the server console keeps spamming "END" (last thing client sends to end transmission). If I check whether the line is not END or null it hangs after the last line of information is sent to the server.

Comment: @Vipar I don't see anywhere inside your while(bClientConnected) loop that you're setting it to false which probably explains the continual "END" print.

Comment: @neith that is a good point..

Comment: @neith I have now fixed the issue completely thanks to you. Would you like to make it an answer and get the rep for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a _sWriter.Flush(); after _sWriter.WriteLine("SEND_PLEJEFAMILIE"); in the client code.

Comment: another option should be enabling AutoFlush

Comment: Doesn't seem like @neith wants to have the reputation for his answer since he gave it before you. But you also provided the right answer and right should be right so you will get the reputation :)

Comment: oh, the comment with his answer was under the line, I didn't notice it. Didn't want to steal his glory, I figured my answer independently :) But anyway, done is done. At least I added the "AutoFlush" as an option ;)

Comment: No sweat. He didn't really answer when I asked him to make it an answer so I guess it's fine ^^